# TCP connection to FPGA board

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, tcp

I'm trying to establish a TCP connection to an FPGA board from my Windows PC. The PC has two Ethernet interfaces, one is connected directly to the FPGA board, the other one is connected to the company network:
[current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPEPo.png)

The problem is, the TCP connection requests are output on the wrong ethernet interface (company network interface) and not on the one where my FPGA board is connected.

Settings of my FPGA board are:
Board IP (static): 192.168.1.10
Netmask : 255.255.255.0
Gateway : 192.168.1.1

Settings of the 2nd PC Ethernet Interface:
IP (static): 192.168.1.4
Netmask : 255.255.255.0
Gateway : 192.168.1.1

Settings of the 1st PC Ethernet Interface:
IP : 160.xx.xx.xxx
Netmask : 255.255.255.0
Gateway : 160.xx.xx.1

Is there some way to force Windwos to Output the TCP packets to a specific IP address on the 2nd Ethernet interface?

Comment: I solved it by adding an ARP table entry...

Comment: What is ARP table entry? A detailed answer would be great.